# How to close google chrome at a particular event using Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, google-chrome

I am using the following JS/JQuery code in order to close the browser at a **particular event**.

**It works perfectly on Internet explorer but not sure why its not working on Google Chrome.**

```
<div class="divRowButton">
   <asp:LinkButton ID="btnContinue" runat="server" CssClass="button buttonText" Width="205px"
      Height="33px" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick ="return CloseBrowser();"></asp:LinkButton>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
       //IE6 Fix, expand the content to full height
       if (jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version.substring(0, 1) == 6) {
           $divH = $("#secHeader");
           $divN = $("#secNav");
           $divF = $("#secFooter");
           var ht = $(window).height() - $divH.height() - $divN.height() - $divF.height();
           $(".divContent").height(ht - 10);
       }
   });

   function CloseBrowser() {
       window.open('', '_self', '');
       window.close();
   }
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

**I changed my above code to the following below code but still it didn't work for chrome.** I am wondering what changes do I need to make in the below code so that it works perfectly for chrome.

```
<div class="divRowButton">
   <asp:LinkButton ID="btnContinue" runat="server" CssClass="button buttonText" Width="205px"
      Height="33px" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick ="return CloseBrowser('quit');"></asp:LinkButton>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
       //IE6 Fix, expand the content to full height
       if (jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version.substring(0, 1) == 6) {
           $divH = $("#secHeader");
           $divN = $("#secNav");
           $divF = $("#secFooter");
           var ht = $(window).height() - $divH.height() - $divN.height() - $divF.height();
           $(".divContent").height(ht - 10);
       }
   });

   function CloseBrowser(cmd) {
       if (cmd == 'quit') {
           open(location, '_self').close();
       }
       return false;
   }
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

The following image will give more idea what changes I did in both of the above codes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem with some functionality, start simple:

```
<body>

<script>
  window.close();
</script>

</body>
```

It works just perfect on every browser.

If you would like to close the window that you previosly opened:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_close

From the question itself, I am not able to determine what you really want to achive? Would you like the window to be closed on some event?

Comment: Yes I want to close my browser at a particular event. I have mentioned 2 codes above. The 1st code work fine for internet explorer but I am not sure why it doesn't work from Chrome. 

In the 2nd code, I tried something different but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I examined your closeBrowser function and rewrote it:

```
<body>
<script>
  var cmd = prompt("Please enter cmd");
  if (cmd == 'quit') {
        window.close();
}
</script>
</body>
```

It is also based on 'cmd'. The value of cmd is taken out of the user prompt.

In addition, your first version of code is fine. You just need to invoke the function after creating it:

```
function CloseBrowser() {
  window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();
       }
CloseBrowser();
```

Now it works on chrome as well. Using this syntax, you can avoid prompt before closing the window. To see the efect, use setTimeout function:

```
setTimeout(CloseBrowser, 5000);
```

It will close the window after 5 seconds.

Comment: I tried with this code `<body>
<script>
  var cmd = prompt("Please enter cmd");
  if (cmd == 'quit') {
        window.close();
}
</script>
</body>`

It did reach till "Please enter cmd" .  After that I enter quit but it didn't close the browser.

Comment: that is very wired cause it works for all my browsers, including chrome...

Comment: I get it now: it just closes the current window. If the window is the only one, it closes the browser...